# extjs building a tree on demand what event shall I capture after click the + simbol

Tags: extjs

I'm building a tree which will be loading its data on demand, so, it will be loading the first level of data, then if I click the `+` it should load that node children, if node is not leaf.
I've tried with `itemclick`, `itemdblclick`, `select`, but none of these events is fired when click the `+`.
Maybe a naive question, how can I capture the click on the `+` or `-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself, and here is what I did:

in the view:

I needed to add: `displayField: 'text'` in the treepanel config and then point all the data to be displayed  to that config.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those events using the `itemexpand` and `itemcollapse` listeners

```
listeners: {
    itemexpand: function(nodeinterface,eOpts){
        console.log('item expanded');
    },
    itemcollapse:function(nodeinterface,eOpts){
        console.log('item collapsed');
    }
},
```

Comment: No I can't. These events are only fired if the node has children, and my tree needs to be populated on demand... and therefore the node has no children yet.

Comment: I'm building the nodes structure myself and then passing it into the store with `store.loadData(mydata, false)`. The nodes are built into an objects array: `var mydata = [{text: 'First', leaf: false}, {text: 'Second', leaf: true}]`... the `leaf` property tells the tree what kind of node to render...

Comment: Are you sure itemclick event isn't fired? I made a fiddle to check it and in my fiddle, the event is fired, can you check it on my fiddle? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s5h"

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me either... I'm using Firefox and Chromium under a Linux Mint Tessa system

Comment: Mr. Matheus, try:  `xtype: 'treepanel'`... it won't do anything... maybe that would be a bug?

Comment: Tried using treepanel and still could get the events https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s5j